# Bootstrap alert doens't show with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Perhaps I missed something in the documentation:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

I want to show an `Alert` (in the `Bootstrap` sense) with `jQuery` when a button is clicked. 
Here a simple snippet:

```js
$("#btnAlert").click(function() {
  $("#success-alert").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible hide" id="success-alert" role="alert">
  <strong>Success! </strong>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">Show</button>
```

It doesn't work. Removing the `hide` class the alert will stay visible, but of course is not what I want.

What am I missing?

Comment: what you want actually then ?

Comment: `$("#btnAlert").click(function() { $("#success-alert").removeClass("hide").show(); }`

Answer (score 2):

try this....

```js
$("#btnAlert").click(function() {
  $("#success-alert").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" style="display:none" id="success-alert" role="alert">
  <strong>Success! </strong>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing class `hide` on click should work.

```js
$("#btnAlert").click(function() {
  $("#success-alert").removeClass('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible hide" id="success-alert" role="alert">
  <strong>Success! </strong>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">Show</button>
```